# Firebase: onAuthStateChanged() method not being picked up in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

I need to used the onAuthStateChanged() method in Firebase auth in the sign-in process of an app I am developing and am trying to use it as I have seen in every source online:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()
```

However, this returns the error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'firebase'
```

Am I importing Firebase auth wrong or has this method been changed in recent updates to Firebase? These are my imports in the file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI
import FirebaseAuthUI
```

And this is my pods file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
  pod 'TwitterCore', '<=3.0.0' 
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

Any tips would be much appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the JavaScript Firebase API includes `onAuthStateChanged`, the Swift API does not.

For Swift see, `addAuthStateDidChangeListener:`. Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-addauthstatedidchangelistener).